# PlainRoute Redirect / onEnter not triggered navigating from child to parent route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using the [alternate syntax](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/DynamicRouting.md) to define my routes using [`PlainRoute`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#plainroute). [It's recommended](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2256#issuecomment-148249068) to use the `onEnter` lifecycle event to trigger a redirect. However, due to the way `onEnter` currently behaves (or at least how I understand it behaving), it's not triggered when navigating from a child route to a parent route. For example, if you navigate from `/profile/foo` to `/profile`, `onEnter` will not be triggered.

Let's look at some code:

```
export default {
  path: 'projects',
  onEnter (next, replace) {
    console.log('1st level deep!')
    if (next.routes.length <= 2) {
      replace('/foo')
    }
  },
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: ':project',
      onEnter (_, replace) {
        console.log('2nd level deep!')
      },
      component: ProjectComponent
    }
  ]
}
```

The parent's onEnter will not be triggered and the redirect won't be able to occur. Does anyone know of a way to trigger `onEnter` that I'm not aware of? `react-router-redux` picks up and broadcasts a location change, but I'd rather rely on `react-router`. Thanks for your time!