# What's the logic behind how React Router processes onEnter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

`react-router` has [some docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#enter-and-leave-hooks) on how `onEnter`/`onLeave` are handled, but I don't understand why traversing *up* the tree would not cause onEnter to be triggered?

For example, if you have the following routes:

- `/`
- `/profile`
- `/profile/:username`

And navigated from `/` to `/profile` to `/profile/boogers`, onEnter would be triggered 3 times. But if you navigate to `/` from `/profile` or `/profile/boogers`, it's not triggered? I would expect that entering a new path with always trigger an onEnter event because you're going to a new url path?

Thanks for your time!

Related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854874/plainroute-redirect-onenter-not-triggered-navigating-from-child-to-parent-rout) as well.

Comment: Why don't you ask the maintainers?

Comment: Oh, [you did](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2256#issuecomment-192544231). SO can help you solve a tech problem, but we can't tell you _why_ decisions were made in repos we don't maintain!

Comment: And so that's worth a downvote? Damned if I do, damned if I don't. Maintainers won't tell me anything and now the community won't help out either 

Comment: [self promotion disclaimer] I made an alternative to react-router called "Pouter": https://github.com/tybro0103/pouter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The routes are considered hierarchical. When you first navigate to /profile `onEnter` would be triggered on both /profile and /. When you then navigate from /profile to /, no `onEnter` is triggered because it is considered that you were already within that parent route.

So, I think that's technically the answer, but I also think it's dumb, IMHO. It does indeed leave you with some serious flaws, which the OP already pointed out in the linked github issue on react-router.

Related is the fact if you navigate from /users/a to /users/b, there is not a hook for that at all. Your only option to implement `componentWillReceiveProps` and check to see if `userId` has changed. Poor separation of concerns. More info: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2547